# Apply angularjs to form input items

Tags: javascript

Currently I want to apply angularjs to my drupal site. The problem is:

It is very hard to me add ng-model attribute to a form input tag.

Is there any way that I can add attribute to a form input tag?

Cheers!

Comment: What's hard about it exactly? `$form['foo']['#attributes']['ng-model'] = 'bar';` ( or data-ng-model if you're concerned with validity) should be as complicated as it gets really

Comment: But how can I do this to only the input html tag for each item?

Comment: By using the code above. Sorry but I'm not sure what you're asking, applying an attribute to a form element is literally as straightforward as that one line

Comment: So for each form item, is has a label and an input tag with a parent div wrapping around them. I only want to add the attribute to the input tag rather than to the form tag. Is it clear?

Comment: Rather than assuming the code I've given you doesn't work, why don't you try it? That's not clear to me ;)

Comment: Sorry never try to do that before. But ok, I am trying now. Thanks for that.